# Jersey 1.16: How do you view xsd in browser?

Tags: web-services, xsd, jersey

I am been struggling to get the XSD for my project to be shown in the browser. I have the WADL created and I just need the XSD for the response and request if possible. Does anyone know how to do this? The XSDs are in a separate project from the web service but can be in the web service if needed. The web service has a dependency on the XSD project.

Comment: The easiest way would be to cram the schema documents in a location within the web content folder (same as JSPs, CSS, JS, etc.). Another option is to place them in a package, load them as resources and expose them using Jersey. Both ways are somewhat far-fetched but I don't know if there's a 'right' way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my issue. I just used the generated xsd by Jersey. The reason it was not generating the xsd for me was the methods in the Java class were passing a String not the JAXB classes that were created by the xsd.

Answer (score 0):

By "the browser" do you mean an off-the-shelf Web browser?

If so, one solution is to exploit the fact that the XSD schema documents are XML documents by giving them an xml-stylesheet processing instruction and a stylesheet to make them display in Web browsers.  As an example:  the W3C XML Schema WG did this with [the schema for the XSD test suite](http://www.w3.org/XML/2004/xml-schema-test-suite/AnnotatedTSSchema.xsd); the Service Modeling Language WG did the same thing with [their schema](http://www.w3.org/2008/09/sml-schema.xsd).  (The [stylesheet the two WGs use](http://www.w3.org/XML/2004/xml-schema-test-suite/xsd.xsl) is the same and is available under the W3C document and software licenses.)